# How to rename computer after join the domain in PowerShell v2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am using PowerShell 2.0 and using the following code to join domain:

```bsh
$domain = "test.org.hk"
$password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$username = "$domain\Administrator" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential
```

After joining the domain, I use the following code to rename computer:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Rename($nameStr)
```

I find that I cannot change computer name.

But, if I don't join the domain, I can use this code to change computer name.

Therefore, how to rename computer after join the domain in PowerShell v2.0?

Comment: You need to reboot first.

Comment: How to join the domain and rename computer together before reboot the computer?

Comment: Upgrade to PowerShell v3.